# How to input return whitespace in ERB template?

Tags: ruby, html, whitespace

by using sinatra and I want generate a webVTT, which take the whitespaces into account, to make a identical return file like:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:22.865 --> 00:00:30.413
Now we are gonna focus on the hihats, and this is where you actually get to hold these sticks. And

2
00:00:30.416 --> 00:00:37.745
I play matched grip which is where your both the sticks are held in the same way, a lot of people called traditional grip,
```

I made the following code, with iterate a hash object converted from json:

```
WEBVTT

<% @sub_json['data'].each_with_index do |value, index|%>
    <%= index+1 %>
    <%= value['start'].to_time %>--><%= value['end'].to_time%> 
    <%= value['en'] %>
    <%= %>
<% end %>
```

the result doesn't work, I paste the request from browser to vim and use `set list!` to show all the whitespaces, it seems all the return whitespaces are removed, I guess this is the reason that my code doesn't work

anyone know how to add whitespaces to make the code working?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the way Sinatra is evaluating the ERB. Normally your code would have the whitespaces there, and you would have to use something like `<%= some code -%>` to remove trailing whitespace (notice the trailing dash). Sinatra may change the default [trim_mode](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) when evaluating the ERB. You'd have to dig around in the internals to find that out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register vtt as a mime type in initializers/mime_types.rb? Actually, that's a Rails file, but I'd guess you have to do something similar for Sinatra.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).